# running bash script on server to execute multiple MATLAB scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, matlab

I'm not a programmer, just a chemist. I'm writing a bash script, which I want to run on the server and expect it to do the following:

1. Open a terminal
2. Loop over folders `slave_1`, `slave_2`, ..., `slave_N`
   for each folder open a tab, start up MATLAB (`maltab -nodesktop`), cd to the folder, and run the script `slave_process`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
gnome-terminal --tab  --working-directory="/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin" --command='./matlab -nodesktop; cd /mnt/projects/slave_$i; -nosplash -r slave_process'
done

exit 0
```

Can some help me to get the script to work? I'm not in the sudoers file, so can't change anything on the server.

**Update. The answer by @muru does the trick but it starts a new terminal at each loop iteration, which is a pain since I need to run around 200 MATLAB instances.** I want to have multiple tabs in the same terminal (or no terminal at all is fine as well).
Here is my modified code, which does not work:

```
args=()
for i in {1..5}; do
    cmd=working-directory='/mnt/projects/slave_$i' --command='/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r slave_process'
    args+=(--tab-with-profile=Default -e "sh -c \"$cmd; bash\"")
done

gnome-terminal "${args[@]}"
```

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

- Variable expansion doesn't work inside single quotes `''` - so `slave_$i` in the second part of your command will remain `slave_$i`.
- Since you know the path of the `matlab` command, run it directly using the full path, instead of starting in that directory and using `./matlab`.
- If `-nosplash -r slave_process` are arguments to `matlab`, they should be in the same command.
- `exit 0` is unnecessary.

Consider something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
    gnome-terminal --tab  --working-directory="/mnt/projects/slave_$i" \
      --command='/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r slave_process'
done
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. The last question though. Because of {gnome-terminal} on each line, each loop iteration starts a new terminal. How to modify it to have a new tab for each loop iteration in the same terminal?

Comment: I'm curious - why do you need a terminal at all?

Comment: I want to monitor the progress of the script in each folder (I'm doing data fitting and printing out the progress to the window). Could you please, show both versions, with and without any terminal?